# Save a hash into an HSTORE column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails JOB that Loops through my Review objects and is supposed to post with it's specific params pertaining to the product that is being reviewed. what I want is the below hash to exist in a non reviews object. Where it says review.(whatever) I want that as actual ruby code and not the value that comes from running that. Later when I put it through the submission job. I want that has for the HTTP post like such. (myurl where the url would go)

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('myurl'), survey.product.submithash)
```

and instead of survey.product.submithash it would call this hash.

```
{'ApiVersion'=>'5.4','Action'=>'preview','Rating'=>review.QandA["Overall Rating"], 'ReviewText'=>review.QandA["Review"],'Title'=>review.QandA["Headline"],'UserNickname'=>review.QandA["Nickname"],'useremail'=>review.QandA["Your Email"],'UserLocation'=> review.user.location, 'isRecommended'=>review.QandA["Would you recommend this product?"]}
```

How do I go about doing this?
I am on rails 4.2.5.1
ruby 2.2.X
and I am using postgres 9.4.5 (if that matters)

Comment: look into serialization and see if that does what you want /need

Comment: @Doon, he has already specified that he is using a `hstore` column with is a key/val type column. `serialization` is not relevant.

Comment: Why not use JSON and Postgres? Those two fit together seamlessly. HSTORE was the only option prior to Postgres 9.3, but the new JSON store is significantly better.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to take a hash and fill it in with default options? Thats easy - `hash.merge(defaults_hash)`. If you are looking to do that on the database level however I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: Hmm, appently you can do that with JSON columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518078/setting-default-value-for-a-json-column

Comment: Can you please edit the question?

Comment: However this sounds like a very overcomplicated solution to an invented problem. If you are creating a nested record you don't need to send all the params of the parent record. You simply need an ID. You might want to take a step back and consider if this is an XY problem.

Comment: @max I understand what you mean but the issue is that I am getting all my info from an external source. So my review object contains a hash of all the info plus some other information I use as variables

Comment: btw someone edited my question which is misleading I think. is the template concept hard to grasp? I checked the dictionary and it is what I am asking for, I think I am correctly explaining my question, but I guess I am not

Comment: Can you edit the question and try to make it less abstract maybe? Show what the data you are getting looks like and how you want to use it. Code, even metacode usually helps.

Comment: Yea i have to be careful as legally I cant show the info. I'll rewrite the question